# Is it possible to merge an existing lite and a full version (inside the lite version plus in-app billing)?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, android-lvl

I have two apps on android market:
1) LITE/FREE - with ads and less content
2) FULL/PAID - without ads and full content

Is it possible to merge them together inside the LITE app using the in-app billing and maintain the users that bought the FULL version? How?

Basically:
* use the LITE package to add in-app billing
* in-app billing should use the FULL android market database

Thanks!

Comment: I Don't think so, package names are how the market Identifies separate apps. You're best bet is probably prompt the users of whichever has less to install the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not (as of now). See [this Google I/O video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnSNCXR9fbY#at=2273) where you're exact problem is discussed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is possible the reason it was a problem for the guy in the video is because he already has customers whom have purchased the license in a different way and he will not be able to transfer those purchases to the in app billing purchase - this could be worked around by either having a server which will manage the purchases for you and inquiring via your server and not the Google lvl, or by providing and maintaining support for both methods of purchase (but this would be ugly).

Comment: But I also have customers whom have purchased the full app license and I didn't have any server to manage it!

Comment: "providing and maintaining support for both methods of purchase" Can you explain what you mean? AFAICT, the only way to do that would be to continue having two separate apps.